# Is there any way to let reedem users in-app points to money automatically?

Tags: node.js, paypal, google-play, google-play-services

So I have an app, where you can earn points for certain interactions. I want to let users be able to redeem those points for money based on a conversion rate. Now I want to automate this process, such that users can redeem their points by just typing, for example, their e-mail address and then receiving the money via PayPal or anything else. My first thought was to give users Google Play credits like Google Opinion Rewards, but this is not possible for developers? Or is it? I couldn't find anything about it? And the only way to use PayPal for this process is to use PayPal PAyouts, which can only be used after having made a turnover of 5000$, three months in a row, which takes too long and also is a bit much money. Is there any way to automatically transfer money to users with the help of a server and, for example, a REST API?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I am looking for something similar

Comment: Unfortunately no